# Limitations on the Number of Items and Nesting Levels in Windows 11 File Explorer Context

Tags: windows-11, shell-extensions

I am developing an extension for Windows 11 File Explorer and have encountered an issue. In my extension, I create a context menu item with several nested items. For one of these nested items, I add a few more nested items. As a result, my main menu item and the first-level nested items are displayed in the File Explorer context menu, but the second-level nested items are not displayed.

Interestingly, if I choose the "Show more options" in the context menu, all items are displayed correctly, which indirectly indicates that the code is written correctly.

I have been unable to find any official information on whether there are limitations on the number of items in the context menu or on the number of nesting levels. Can anyone share information or experience on this issue?

Thank you in advance!

I implemented the IExplorerCommand interface to create a custom context menu for Windows 11 File Explorer. My menu has a main item with several first-level nested items. One of these first-level items has additional second-level nested items. I expected all these items to be displayed in the context menu when right-clicking in File Explorer. However, only the main item and the first-level nested items are displayed. The second-level nested items are missing unless I choose the "Show more options" in the context menu.

Comment: Are you implemening IContextMenu or your code base exclusively on IExplorerCommand? https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/ Do you have a reproducing sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my implementation, I have exclusively used the IExplorerCommand interface. I am aware that some solutions, like TortoiseGit, implement both IContextMenu and IExplorerCommand. However, the rationale behind using both interfaces simultaneously is not clear to me.

For my implementation, I took inspiration from this example: 
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3307#issuecomment-1115015581

Comment: And does this samples have a high number of nested levels? As I said w/o some reproducing code, we can't do nothing more to help.